# probability business mathematics

Tags: probability

A company owns a fleet of 20 cars, each having either Manual or automatic transmission and either 2 or 4 doors. it is reported that 13 cars are 2-door models and, of these, 12 have automatic transmission. There are only 4 cars with manual transmission. If a car is picked at random from the fleet , calculate the probability that it is:

a) automatic
 b) 4-door
 c) automatic or 2-door
 d) automatic and 2-door
 e) automatic given that it is a 4-door car
 f) 4-door car given it is automatic

What I know is probability for a will be 16/20 and for for 4-doors will be 7/20 .

Comment: Before getting into the probabilities, fill in the missing details on the combined characteristics.  How many 4-door cars?  How many 2-door cars have manual transmission?  How many 4-door cars with automatic, and how many with manual?  Once you get all that together you can read off the probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

First use a two-way table with the given information:

```
        automatic     manual     total
2-door     12                      13
4-door
total                   4          20
```

We can fill in the remaining numbers one by one to get:

```
        automatic     manual     total
2-door     12           1          13
4-door      4           3           7
total      16           4          20
```

So now it should be easy to get a) to d).

Part e) is exactly the same as asking "What is the probability that a random 4-door car is automatic?"; this should also be easy to read off from the table. f) is similar.

Comment: @RobertGomani: "Please help further" sounds extremely rude in English.  The same principle you applied to solve (a) and (b) can be used for the rest.  How many cars are automatic OR four-door?  How many cars are automatic AND four-door?  Of the four-door cars, how many are automatic?  ETc.

Comment: I get it now thanks a lot